# currency format from text to double in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

i have an access database with a price column as **text type** i want to convert it to double to do some comparisons the problem is the column has values that looks like the following:

```
5.22
2.5$
62.5
34.6$
45.3
65.9$
```

so `Convert.ToDouble` is working fine with the values that does not contain the "$" sign so how can i remove the $ sign from the text before converting it to double?

so basicly the idea is

check if there is "$"

remove "$" from text

covert to double...

also it would be better to delete anything from the number except the decimal point

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `String.Replace`. No need to check for "$". If it is there, it will be replaced.

```
    Dim value1 As String = "12.7$"
    Dim value2 As String = value1.Replace("$", "")
    MessageBox.Show(value2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `Double` for currency. Use `Decimal`.

And sorry, I'm coming from C#, but how about:

```cs
string str = "34.6$";
if (str.EndsWith("$"))
    str = str.Substring(0, str.Length-1);

var value = Decimal.Parse(str);
```

Crudely converted:

```vb
Dim str As String = "34.6$"
If str.EndsWith("$") Then
    str = str.Substring(0, str.Length - 1)
End If

Dim value = [Decimal].Parse(str)
```